# Automate CMake build using C++ script

Tags: c++, build, cmake, cmake-gui

I would like to automate the build of CMake using an MSVC C++ script instead of using CMake-gui to generate the build or CMake terminal or using the CMake integrated on MSVC 2017 by right click on the CMakeLists.txt to build it manually. Assume we have a project (name it: initialize) that includes the CMakeLists.txt and initialize.cpp, so my question is how I can convert these commands into a C++ code, assume build_initialize.cpp:

- mkdir build
- cd build/
- cmake ..

So, the requirement of this tiny C++ code is to

- Set the path to this project
- Create build folder
- Run CMake

At the end if I execute build_initialize.exe, the job is just to build the initialize.cpp using CMake. The goal is to test if the build is success or not as a test case within another project that has several test cases.

You may ask, why I didnot include it to the top CMakelists.txt, and then build it from the beginning using CMake. If I am going to do that, I will get an executable file. As a result, by running the ctest of CMake, the initialize.exe will require a pace of hardware. This is not the goal. My goal is just to build it. If I run build_initialize.exe, just repeat the build using CMake without initialize.exe execution.

Sorry, it could be very simple, but I lack the good experience either in C++ or CMake. Two days have been lost without success.

Comment: You create scripts in scripting languages like Python, Perl etc. C++ is not one.

Comment: On Windows consider using the builtin PowerShell scripting ability (or failing that batch files).

Comment: I expect that your problem is you called `system()` more than 1 time in your `c++` code or did not escape your strings properly. Although theses are just guesses since you did not provide any code.

Comment: If you are using Git for Windows just use a bash script.  There are much easier ways than using C++.

Comment: Thanks for those comments. The problem is that I need to do it in C++, since there is some work is already done in C++, the missing part is to automate the CMake build using C++ script.

Comment: Then show what you have tried and failed. Remember we generally don't write code for you at StackOverflow however we will attempt to fix your broken code. Please edit your question and add a minimal example of your attempt: [mcve]

Comment: You are right. However, I have no clue, how I can call the CMake from C++ Code to build a CMake project similar to what we are doing using the terminal of Cygwin or CMake Gui. I did an intensive search on the web, but I did not find a hint to do it. You may ask, we I didnot include it to the top CMakelists.txt, please look to the question, I re-edit it.

Comment: There are probably a few ways to run an executable from a C++ program.  Once such method is: [system()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Thanks @Fred for the hint to use [system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem?view=vs-2019) . This is what I am looking for.  Drescherjm has already mentioned to it, but I did not get his comment, since I had no information about it.

Comment: Note that newer versions of cmake support `cmake -S path_to_src -B path_to_bld`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all of you for the comments. The answer has been given by @Fred. To run cmake from C++ script, simply the system() can be used such as: System(cmake -S path_to_src -B path_to_bld). 
Useful link: https://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284392&answer=1044654269